# Hand-histories of successful players

Tags: hand-history

Are there any good players who have uploaded some of their hand-histories somewhere?  I am looking for at least a few thousand unfiltered hands including hole-cards. I need this to learn how the best play.

Comment: I don't think this is the sort of question we are looking for on this site. Its not likely to be useful to anyone. Please either rephrase it and expend on why you need it, or delete the question.

Comment: And just an FYI, sites that sell hand histories are doing so against the wishes of the people that were in the hands as well as against the wishes of the online poker sites themselves. So you'll generally want to avoid them.

Comment: I think it's not only a valid, but a good question, sadly there is no shortage of self-righteous people who can't stop second-guessing. If questions whose answers have the potential to lead to morally questionable behaviour I'd suggest to make it explicitly so in the faq and be done with it. No need to engage in passive agressive discussions.

Comment: You shouldn't look at hand histories of other players. It's better to learn by playing. If you can't improve anymore, you probably are on the edge of your game.

Comment: @ValentinGrégoire By that argument why are you even on this site.  Learn by playing.

Comment: Maybe post on http://opendata.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

There are many better ways to learn than that. You're unlikely to find hand histories from professional, or highly skilled amateurs, easily available online. Releasing said hand histories would be suicide. The closest your going to get, and easily one of the most productive ways to improve your online poker game, is to watch videos of skilled players playing. They will either explain what they're doing in real time or review their play afterwards. Reading poker books, online poker forums, watching videos, and so on, is definitely more productive than going through hand histories of high stakes pro's. You would have no idea why they're doing what they're doing.

There are generally two types of players a poker regular has to concern himself with. Fish and other regulars. When playing fish all said player has to do is identify the fish's strategy and implement the maximally exploitative response. However, against another regular, said player also has to be concerned about **balancing** their own strategy as well. Reviewing hand histories between two regulars without knowing any poker theory, or the history between both players, will only teach you extremely bad habits.

Below are some training sites that release high quality instructional videos from professionals. And yes, you have to pay for them.

- [Cardrunners](https://www.cardrunners.com/)
- [Deuces Cracked](https://www.deucescracked.com/)
- [Run It Once](http://www.runitonce.com/)
- [Tournament Poker Edge](http://www.tournamentpokeredge.com/)

Answer (score 1):

There are many sites that sell hand histories:

[Try searching Google.](http://bit.ly/1nhmeLd)

If you're just looking for the way "good" players play, then you should be able to deduce that for yourself. For example, import the purchased hand histories into Holdem Manager or Poker Tracker or whatever you prefer. Filter the data for the kind of players you're looking for (e.g., look for players with large samples and good win rates in the games you want to play in). Then just review those hands.

It's pretty straightforward if you want to do this. Just search Google.